How can I get a clear waveform of current and voltage of a micro grid to feed into an Arduino?
Imagine that I have a microgrid consisting of solar panels, a wind turbine, batteries, and various loads. I need the waveforms of the system current and voltage, as well as the phase shift between them, as input values for my Arduino Nano microcontroller.
Which measurement or monitoring system would be most suitable for laboratory testing? The zero-crossing point of the current is essential for the microcontroller, so the RMS value alone is not sufficient. I require the waveforms of current and voltage, along with the phase shift.

With Arduino controller ...
You need take "equally" time spaced (uses Interrupt Timer Task), and apply Fourier formulas.
(@50 Hz, timer every 2 or 1ms, 11 or 21 points, max 8 channels, voltages and currents)
Note that as "acquisition" takes some time (some 100 us) on Arduino, you need "software correcting" time delay (and so "phase") between samples.
Zero crossing point is "not" needed, you need only two "software" references channels.
Note also that this method should not be "real time" task because of "calculus time" and should used only in "steady" measurements.
